# Adding additional relation in many to many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, uml

Current diagram:
[image]

Explanation:

Activity - Table with all activities, as: jogging, swimming...

Person: All persons clients, trainers etc.

People can take part in many activities and activities can have many members.
I want also include person(type: Trainer), who leads activity. Person can lead many activities, but activity can has only one trainer.
How include my relation in diagram. Maybe new arrow between Activity and Person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new association will serve your purpose best. You might name the opposite of the `+trainer` as `+courseLead` to tell that its a course led by the trainer.

[image]

I used `PersonActivity` (corresponds to you `ActivityReservation`) as an association class.